# (VISUAL STUDIO) Modify c++ direct3d game template to make it transparent, stay topmost, and click throughable

Tags: directx, direct3d, steam

In my long hours of using programs via steam using non-steam game functionality, I have finally grown to the point of really desiring steam overlay functionality while 'ingame'.

Since, in most cases, you need a directx/OpenGL/Vulkan/etc program to hook the steam overlay properly, I am trying to make a directx 'game' that will run fullscreen, stay topmost, have no titlebar, be click-throughable, have a transparent window, and when it launches it will automatically run a .bat file, so that way you can add the pseudo 'game' to steam and rename it your program's actual name (i.e. Adobe Photoshop), and when you launch the 'game' it will run the .bat file where you can place a start command to launch, for example, Adobe Photoshop.

I used the Direct3d Win32 Game template in the C++ new project options of Visual Studio 2013, and edited       ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow); to ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED); so the 'game' runs fullscreen now and the steam overlay can hook into it just fine, but I am unsure how to do the rest of what I am seeking. Sorry, I am not that good with C++.

This would be useful for people who like to run non-steam programs pretty often. Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:
Thinking, possibly the 'game' would need to have some sort of functionality that will keep the 'game' in focus all the time, so that way it will always accept the shift+tab shortcut for the steam overlay.

Comment: Are you referring to the template from [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) or something else?

Comment: Yeah, its the direct3d win32 game template, under C++.  I am using Visual Studio 2013.